# How to create a certain configuration given below in HTML?

Tags: html

For certain project I want to create a configuration like shown below in image in HTML.

[image]

This is a circular ring (bounded by two circles) divided into 10 equal cells and each cell have different color (out of 10 different colors) . Each cell also has a digit (0-9) corresponds to it and placement of digits is fixed (for example: top cell with black color has digit '0' and next cell has digit '1' in clock wise direction). The color of each cell have to change dynamically (on each session) and all cells have unique colors out of 10 different colors. I want to write HTML code for it.

My approach is :
first I draw two circles and divide into 10 equal cells using line geometry. but problem is how to fill color in each cell !!

Any suggestions !!!  Please give me HTML code or correct approach to do this.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/) See the [FAQ], please.

Comment: I have drawn two co-centric circles with different radius value and then using center of these circles drawn lines to divide into 10 equal parts. but how to fill color into particular cell and a particular digit in it ?

Comment: Show your existing code and HTML.

Answer (score 0):

there is a plugin called `Set Text on a Circle` , it may be useful for you , try it here http://css-tricks.com/set-text-on-a-circle/