# How can I create a circle consisting of arc segments using css and javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've looked on the internet for quite a while now, but am unable to find the answer. I'm fairly new to web development and am trying to learn css/html and javascript.

I want to create a circle consisting of 12 segments and I also want to have control over each segment (i.e being able to change the colour at will and also maybe some sort of animation, for example segment 1 turning red and then segment 2 subsequently turning blue).

I'm trying to achieve a look similar to this:

[image: circle broken into segments]

Each segment is initially white and will only change colour when specified.

Can someone please point me in the right direction on the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: there is already a thread regarding your question with a solution on stackoverflow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14184494/segments-in-a-circle-using-css3

Comment: @kkreft I did see that, but I'm not trying to make slices - rather I want control of the arcs

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14383088/how-to-create-a-certain-configuration-given-below-in-html

I also looked at the above question but there was no solution. That user has the exact same problem as me

Comment: https://sarasoueidan.com/tools/circulus/

Comment: I did this a while ago with SVG, have a play around here: https://jsfiddle.net/ctrlfrk/k275asjf/5/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Doughnut chart from ChartJS. Just be sure to split the doughnut into 12 equal groups of data (in my example I'll use 1 for all twelve data points). This will make them all the same size. You can then individually control their colors, and update the chart after.

https://jsfiddle.net/8t8tmc0q/

The necessary HTML:

```
<canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
```

And JavaScript:

```
Chart.defaults.global.legend.display = false;
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'doughnut',
  data: {
    labels: ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11','12'],
    datasets: [{
      data: [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
      backgroundColor: [
        'white',
        'white',
        'white',
        'white',
        'white',
        'white',
        'white',
        'white',
        'white',
        'white',
        'white',
        'white'
      ],
      borderColor: 'black',
      borderWidth: 1
    }]
  }
});
```

Then, to update the colors, you just specify which section you want to update, and use the `myChart.update()` function to draw the change:

```
myChart.data.datasets[0].backgroundColor[5] = 'red'
myChart.update();
```